# App Store wont accept Speech-to-Text App

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I have developed a STT app using Bluemix and Watson, on iOS that is working well in test mode.

My app is written in Objective-C but uses the Swift bridging to functions that invoke the STT. I have set the build settings to say that the app uses Swift.

I followed the example, creating the frameworks using Carthage. I have re-generated these yesterday many times.

However, when I try to upload to the app store using Xcode I get the following:

> This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)

So I export the ipa and try the Application Loader, with which I get the following FOR EACH FRAMEWORK:

> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for
>   MY.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework contains unsupported
>   architectures '[x86_64, i386]’." ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment
>   Alignment. The app binary at
>   'My.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' does not have proper
>   segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode
>   version.”
>
> WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable ‘
>   ayload/My.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework' is not a Position
>   Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are
>   configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to
>   Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in
>   the iOS Developer Library.”

and in addition:

> ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the
>   LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the
>   binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been
>   built with Apple's linker."

I have tried to adjust the build settings but I have not been able to get Apple to accept this app.

Lastly. I have been uploading this app to the App Store without the Watson frameworks, last time on Monday. When I integrated the Watson STT items, it now does not work.

Thoughts / Ideas?

Thanks Clive

Comment: your "Alamofire.framework" don't have support of [x86_64, i386], find and replace it with framework which supports all architectures.

Comment: [x86_64, i386] Is for Intel processors not iPhone/iPad which is iOS (armv7, armv7s, arm64). Are you sending the simulators ipa to the App Store? Did you build the app in xcode?

Comment: Hi Kev, Thanks for your thoughts.I built for distribution from Xcode and when I kept getting the helpful "Try again (22421)" error, then I built adhoc for app store distribution before trying Application Loader. As said this is not just for the Alamofire framework, it is for all Watson Bluemix frameworks that are required for STT to work. Including: Freddy,Restkit,SpeechToTextV1 and Starscream. Has anyone build a STT app with these frameworks and put it on the app store? Thanks Clive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't get to your question sooner! I was away for the long holiday weekend. I just replied to your original question on [dW Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/285113/app-store-wont-accept-stt-app.html#answer-285911). Feel free to follow up with me there, here, or with an issue in the repository--whatever is most convenient for you.

Thanks!
Glenn

Comment: That fixed it, I still had the 22421 error from Xcode, but was able to upload using Application Loader. I will let you know if any issues with apple approval. Thanks Clive